# How can I use CoffeeScript sourcemaps in error handling using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gulp

I am writing a NodeJS application. I thought that I would give CoffeeScript a try. I am using gulp to convert my .js files to .coffee files along with the created the source maps. How can I have the console log out the errors pointing to the .coffee files instead of the .js files?

Comment: You mean the lines in stack traces ?

Comment: Yes. So when I go to debug I can look at my .coffee file. Right now I have to go to my .js file to see what was wrong and then fix it in my .coffee file.

Comment: Are you looking for that: https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support ?

Comment: I am using gulp to compile my files and start my server. Would I be able to use that with gulp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

**Compile** your **frontend code** with gulp-coffee and gulp-sourcemaps and Chrome will use these sourcemaps automaticly.

Do **not** compile your **backend code**, instead run it with the `coffee` command.

Doing so all your Stack Traces and Error Lines will be shown corretly.

When writing your server logic in coffee script your should add a start script in your package.json, for example:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1", // not required but nice to have
  "postinstall": "bower i", // not required but nice to have
  "start": "coffee server.js"
}
```

Now you can start your server by calling `npm start` as you should.

Comment: Ah. This helped me. I was completely wrong on the concept. I understand it now, and it is working!